# Monero or Bitmonero?

Tags: monerod, history, release-naming

If Monero is official name of this project, why is the name bitmonero still commonly used?

Even the daemon is named bitmonerod. Are both names Monero or Bitmonero considered correct?

Comment: Amusingly, a new namespace in the GUI code was recently named Bitmonero...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Bitmonerod was the original name provided by [thankful_for_today](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=233561)

The community decided to take over the project from TFT following some disagreements and renamed it Monero. The name bitmonerod is still used to refer to the Monero daemon but bitmonero is no longer a correct name for the project. [thankful_for_today](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=233561) disappeared and has not posted on Bitcointalk since June 30, 2014.

In addition to changing the name, the trading symbol was also briefly changed to BMR to MRO before the Monero community settles on XMR. XMR was chosen for a specific reason:

> The official ISO 4217 standard specifies three-letter ("Alpha-3") codes for currencies worldwide. Codes beginning with "X", among others, are reserved for special purposes such as non-currency commodities.

Answer (score 18):

`Bitmonerod` was inherited from the original version named Bitmonero. There is a [plan to do away with these legacy bits](https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero/issues/80#issuecomment-223596750),`bitmonerod` may be renamed to `monero-daemon` and `simplewallet` to `monero-wallet-cli`.

Answer (score 10):

I'm sure the `bitmonero` name will hang around for a bit longer, even after the changes that lethos3 linked to, but as an interesting aside: since "Monero" means "coin" in Esperanto "bitmonero" literally means "bit coin"!

Answer (score 5):

There was a recent [pull request](https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero/pull/891) which attempted to change to another name `Moonero`.

The pull request was not merged and the [plan](https://github.com/monero-project/bitmonero/issues/80#issuecomment-223596750) mentioned by lethos3 remains in place.