# Why is it called Monero?

Tags: history, release-naming

Why is Monero called Monero? Shouldn't it have a cool tech-sounding name like Bitcoin or Interslice or Globalcom?

Comment: This may or may not be a duplicate because it explains how the name was inherited but does not fully explain why a change to another name never occured http://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/243/monero-or-bitmonero

Comment: another partial answer:  http://monero.stackexchange.com/a/1024/11  The question is also somewhat speculative as the "why" is hard to answer

Comment: We should consider changing it to Intercoinslicewebcom.

Comment: I was hoping someone would go into the whole "Monero is esperanto, esperanto is a constructed language" thing... how more likely than not anyone in the world might understand what Monero is because language yada yada yada.

Answer (score 9):

Monero translates to coin in Esperanto. The name of the original project that Monero is based on was called BitMonero, or literally BitCoin in Esperanto.

Answer (score 9):

As revler1082 has already said, Monero translates to coin in Esperanto. In its early existence Monero used to be called Bitmonero (which translates to Bitcoin in Esperanto). During the community [take-over](https://forum.getmonero.org/20/general-discussion/211/history-of-monero) the community decided to drop the "bit" part and stick with Monero. The name Monero actually makes sense if you look at other languages. That is:

> The word for "money" and/or "coin" in the most spoken European languages:
>
> - English: money (money)
> - Spanish: dinero (money) / monedar (coin)
> - Russian: монета (coin) [sounds like "maneta"]
> - Portuguese: dinheiro (money) / moeda (coin
> - French: monnaie (money/coin)
> - German: Münze (coin)
> - Italian: denaro (money) / moneta (coin)
> - Polish: moneta (coin)
> - Ukrainian: монета (coin)
> - Romanian: monedă (coin)
> - Dutch: munt (coin)
> - Serbian: монета (money)
> - Irish: mona (money)
> - Estonian: monēta (money)
> - Lithuanian: moneta (money)
>
> So esperanto for money (mono) and coin (monero) seems to be a very good fit for a lot of languages!

**Source:** https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/4aw7xf/pretty_brutal_thread_on_4chan_people_hate_the/d14qe2m

Comment: Agreed. I had similar concerns about the name initially, until I understood how much though went Monero's  esperanto/ worldly origin.