# How to pronounce Monero correctly

Tags: monero-community, esperanto

I would like know how to pronounce monero correctly so when I talk about it, I can give people the right information.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Mon-air-oh"

with the stress on the second syllable - that's how Fluffypony pronounces it on all of the presentations or interviews I've heard him give. And almost everyone else for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

[Given that Monero comes from Esperanto](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1325/why-is-it-called-monero/1326#1326), it'd probably be best to use Esperanto's pronunciation. As u/Bagatell_ pointed out on Reddit, you can use Google Translate for this:

> https://translate.google.com/#eo/en/monero has audio

Other suggested pronunciations can be found here:

https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/5kska9/how_is_monero_pronounced/